# Запись в XML файл происходит долго

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли ускорить запись в XML файл, может быть есть другой способ записи, более быстрый?

```
public void test(List<Zapis> zapisList) {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(AppConstants.filePath + "file.xml")) {
        writeXML(out, zapisList);
    } catch (XMLStreamException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Метод записи

```
private void writeXML(OutputStream outputStream, List<Zapis> zapisList) throws XMLStreamException {
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(outputStream);

    writer.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");

    writer.writeStartElement("zl_list");

    Zglv zglv = new Zglv("1", "A", "1.14", UtilDate.getCurrentDate(), yearMonth);
    WriteXmlSegments.writeZglv(writer, zglv);

    for (Zapis zapis : zapisList) {
        WriteXmlSegments.writeZapis(writer, zapis);
    }

    for (Vrachi vrachi : vrachiList) {
        WriteXmlSegments.writeVrachi(writer, vrachi);
    }

    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeEndDocument();

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

В классе `WriteXmlSegments` тоже похожие методы, для записи сегментов. Если записей много (30000 тыс. например) долго идет запись.

Comment: не очень понимаю код, но в общем случае, если пишете в файл, то лучше писать один большой блок, чем много маленьких. То есть если вы можете добавить кеш при записи или сначала сформировать строку в памяти, а потом всю её записать - то скорость будет максимальной.

Comment: возможно стоит использовать BufferedOutputStream

Comment: изучите другие xml-движки/ SAX и т.п., может и новое что появилось https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047391/fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-create-xml

Comment: https://medium.com/@techisbeautiful/efficient-and-effective-xml-processing-in-java-a-practical-guide-3da3c2a7c19b

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сохранение данных в XML файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506864/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-xml-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Comment: Странная ситуация.. Если запускать программу через Intellij, то нормально записывает данные в XML, а если создавать исполняемый jar файл, то XML не формируется вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Как советовали выше использовал `BufferedOutputStream` , стало быстрее.

```
public void createFile(List<Zapis> zapisList) {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(AppConstants.filePath + AppConstants.FILE_NAME + yearMonth + ".xml");
         BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(out)) {
        writeXML(bufferedOutputStream, ZapisList);
    } catch (XMLStreamException | IOException e) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            mainController.getLogs().appendText(e.toString());
        });
    }
}

private void writeXML(BufferedOutputStream outputStream, List<Zapis> zapisList) throws XMLStreamException {
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");

    writer.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");

    writer.writeStartElement("list");

    Zglv zglv = new Zglv("1", "A", "1.14", UtilDate.getCurrentDate(), "file" + yearMonth);
    WriteXmlSegments.writeZglv(writer, zglv);

    for (Zapis zapis : zapisList) {
        WriteXmlSegments.writeZapis(writer, zapis);
    }

    for (Vrachi vrachi : vrachiList) {
        WriteXmlSegments.writeVrachi(writer, vrachi);
    }

    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeEndDocument();

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```